# Why can't I run my android application on another PC on Androidstudio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

So I want to get my Androidstudio App on another PC so I can continue working on the other PC. My problem is that when I try to run the App on the other PC I keep getting the same error message:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\GymBuddy\GymBuddy

Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE

Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE

Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE

Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig

Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata

Task :app:generateDebugResValues

Task :app:generateDebugResources

Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"The file name must end with .xml","sources":[{"file":"C:\GymBuddy\GymBuddy\app\src\main\res\bin\attach.dll"}],"tool":"Resource and asset merger"}

Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
C:\GymBuddy\GymBuddy\app\src\main\res\bin\attach.dll: Error: The file name must end with .xml
```

I don't get how to solve this problem, I alrdy tried to rename it and to delete it. When I delete it the app doesn't work but I also don't get an error. I also tried to import it and not just simply open it. I keep getting the same error message